# Why python watchdog cannot monitor some folder?

Tags: python, watchdog

I am trying to use the ''watchdog'' package in python to monitor the change of my folder.
The following code are copied directly from the watchdog documentation, and it works fine.

```
import sys
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path =  '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while observer.is_alive():
            observer.join(1)
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

However, when I tried to change the "path" variable, the code might not work.
For example, if `path='./build/'`, I can see the changes in './build/' folder as expected, but if `path='./build/result/'`, the terminal prints nothing no matter what changes I make to the corresponding folder.

I don't understand why, and I have to ask for help.

I am using ubuntu-20.04LTS through WSL2.

Comment: Could you added the `import` statements to your code? It would make it easier to reproduce your setup.

Comment: Also, your code is not valid as is, with the first line outdented with respect to the rest. Please make sure you copy code into questions exactly as you have it on your machine, so we can do a pure cut-and-paste to run it elsewhere.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have recreated the correct code on my machine and I cannot reproduce your problem, it works fine for me with values of `path` of increasing depth, with and without the trailing slash. Is there something special about your folders? Are any symlinks, for example, or are they plain folders? And I have to ask the dumb questions: are you sure the path is spelled exactly the same in your code and on your file system? does the process running the watchdog have sufficient permissions to see the result folder?

Comment: Thank you, I have added the ```import``` statement as well as all other code in my python file. Now the code is basically the same as is shown in the documentation [link](https://python-watchdog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#a-simple-example), except for the changes in ```path```. Also, the loop condition is ```observer.is_alive``` instead of ```ovserver.isAlive```, since the later is deprecated and will report a warning.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that I have spelled the path correctly, since otherwise the watchdog will report a problem, instead of simply not printing the changes to terminal.  What's more, something even more strange happened this morning. ```path='./build/'``` doesn't work anymore, although it works fine last night. Now only ```path='.'``` can correctly monitor the corresponding folder.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for fixing the code and testing against my dumb questions. Now, you've got something that's just weird going on. I hope you can figure it out. Another annoying dumb question, have you tried rebooting? A weird filesystem or OS state could be behind this. I've seen too many SO questions where a reboot fixed mysterious or unreproducible problems not to ask...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the code has changed above (and appreciate this is a few years late!) but from first glance doesn't `recursive` have to be set to `True` if you want to monitor changes in sub-folders?

> By default, an watchdog.observers.Observer instance will not monitor
> sub-directories. By passing recursive=True in the call to
> watchdog.observers.Observer.schedule() monitoring entire directory
> trees is ensured.

(https://python-watchdog.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)